# Possible of multiple GHE organisations connect to one single jenkins instance and fetch jobs?

Tags: github, jenkins, devops

I have requirement as per below

"Possible of multiple GHE organisations connect from one single jenkins instance and fetch jobs?"

I know this is possbile,but how to implement this?